# How to change html anchor tag query string

Tags: php, jquery, html, .htaccess, anchor

It is known that URL with `querystring` parameter can be rewritten with `.htaccess.` For example

```
localhost/mynews/category.php?cat=news&subcat=9
```

To

```
localhost/mynews/news/9
```

But is there any way to customize `anchor tag`

```
<a href="category.php?cat=news&subcat=9"></a>
```

which is shown in bottom left corner while `hovering` link.

```
localhost/mynews/category.php?cat=news&subcat=9
```

to

```
localhost/mynews/news/9
```

PHP, jquery/javascript or htaccess, any way can we customize ?

Comment: well yeah you could use javascript to alter the href attribute of each and every anchor tag on the page.

Comment: You have to do that in your application. And no, it is not known that entries in your `.htaccess` change the generated markup

Comment: Your link should look like this in the first place: `< a href="/mynews/news/9">` - otherwise it makes little sense that you implemented the rewriting from `/mynews/news/9` to `category.php?…` to begin with! You need to change this in your HTML, resp. the logic that creates it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `hover` you can get your anchor `href` get `querystring` value rebuild `url` and  set new `url` using `attr` in anchor tag.

```js
var link = '';
$("a").hover(function() {
  link = $(this).attr('href');
  var var1 = $.urlParam('cat', link);
  var var2 = $.urlParam('subcat', link);
  var url = link.split('?')[0] + '/' + var1 + '/' + var2;
  $(this).attr('href', url);

}, function() {
  $(this).attr('href', link);
});
$.urlParam = function(name, link) {
  var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(link);
  if (results == null) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return decodeURI(results[1]) || 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="category.php?cat=news&subcat=9">Hover Me</a>
```

*Note: I take `urlParam`  function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/25359264/965146 and slightly modified it. Rest code are mine.You must reset your `url` when anchor click may be routing didn't get your new `url`*

Comment: Thanks, I tried, while running in code snippet, first time it worked, but after first time every time `/null/` is adding while hovering. I thought it was browser `cache` problem, but `clearing cache` and trying in `other browsers`, still same problem

Comment: @AnandHmt Because when mouse out i am not reset your url so querystring is null. See updated answer.I reset your url when mouse out.

Comment: Thanks very much, this works, but my requirement is `localhost/mynews/news/9` (I've set url as this in htaccess) as asked in question, but I've got extra `category.php` by your answer `localhost/category.php/mynews/news/9`. How to remove `category.php` ?

Comment: Remove `link.split('?')[0] +` from var `url = link.split('?')[0] + '/' + var1 + '/' + var2;`